# Python3: How to get repeated response from user and run through the loop once again

Tags: python

First of all I'm really sorry to ask such a trivial question. I'm completely new to programming. I'm trying to learn some Python. The book I'm following is, "**Python Crash Course - 2nd Edition**". I hope you bare with me. I was trying to solve a problem.
The problem is as follows,

**A movie theater charges different ticket prices depending on a person's age. If a person is under the age of 3, the ticket is free; if they are between 3 and 12, the ticket is $10; and if they are over age 12, the ticket is $15. Write a loop in which you ask users their age, and then tell them the cost of their movie ticket.**

**My Goal**

Actually I solved the problem. I also managed to do some error handling while the user input is other than int by using isdigit() method, which was not asked in the question. Now I'm trying to implement something like my program should ask for a second response from the user. If user says yes, my loop should run again, if no it should end. I'm really sorry for making this so long. I just wanted to be clear as much as possible. **Thanks in advance!**

The commented block is what I tried.

**The Code:**

```
print ("**********Welcome to Super Cinemas**********")
prompt = ("Enter your age to check for ticket price. ")
prompt += ("Enter 'exit' to quit. " )

age = input (prompt)
while age != 'exit':
    if age.isdigit() != True:
        print("Invalid input, please try again..")
        age = input (prompt)
    elif age.isdigit() == True: 
        age = int (age)
        if age < 3:
            print ("Voila, your tickets are free!")
            break
        elif age >= 3 and age <= 12:
            print ("The cost of the ticket is $10")
            break
        elif age >= 13 and age <= 90:       
            print ("The cost of the ticket is $15")
            break
        else: 
            print ("Sorry, exceeding age limits..")
            break
    # repeat = input ("Do you wanna check more? y/n ")
    # if repeat == 'y':
        # continue
    # else:
        # break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a loop that gets age and gives a result, so getting the age should be inside the while loop.

Your age authentication is wrong, let's say you did not enter a proper age (non-digit) and the program asked for another but it would ask to continue to loop afterwards instead of giving a result, this can be solved by using continue instead of getting another age.

Your while loop would continue until end is entered, provided you did not have `break` and `continue`, you would have done it your way, but since you do, the better way would be to say the while loop continues forever until exit was entered for the second question.

You do not need the break statements in the if statements that deal with age, if any of them is executed the others would not be checked. Why did you use them?

If you get 'y', the loop would continue automatically so you do not need to explicitly put the continue statement.

You can simplify some of your expressions:

`age >= 13 and age <= 90` to `3 <= age <= 12`

and

`if age.isdigit() != True` to `if not age.isdigit()`

**Code**

```
while True:
    age = input(prompt)
    if age.isdigit() != True:
        print("Invalid input, please try again..")
        continue
    elif age.isdigit() == True: 
        age = int(age)
        if age < 3:
            print("Voila, your tickets are free!")
        elif age >= 3 and age <= 12:
            print("The cost of the ticket is $10")
        elif age >= 13 and age <= 90:
            print("The cost of the ticket is $15")
        else: 
            print("Sorry, exceeding age limits..")
    repeat = input("Do you wanna check more? y/n ")
    if repeat != 'y':
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining me so very clearly, that's what I was trying to achieve. Now I understand the logic very well!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can give you. Feel free to ask wherever you may not understand.

```
def print_ticket():
    while True:
        print("**********Welcome to Super Cinemas**********")
        age = input("Enter your age to check for ticket price: ")
        while not age.isdigit():
            age = input("Invalid input! Enter your age to check for ticket price: ")
        age = int(age)
        if age < 3:
            print("Voila, your tickets are free!")
        elif 3 <= age <= 12:
            print("The cost of the ticket is $10")
        elif 13 <= age <= 90:
            print("The cost of the ticket is $15")
        else:
            print("Sorry, exceeding age limits..")
        generate_more = input("Do you want to generate more tickets? (Yes/No): ")
        generate_more = generate_more.upper()

        while generate_more != "YES" and generate_more != "Y" and generate_more != "NO" and generate_more != "N":
            generate_more = str(input("Invalid response! Do you want to generate more tickets? (Yes/No): ")).upper()
        if generate_more == "NO" or generate_more == "N":
            print("Goodbye...!")
            break


print_ticket()
```

Comment: This one works too. Now I learned about the possibilities of solving a problem in different ways. Thanks!